# How do I force gridLayout to make each cell the same size? Also how do I get rid off unnecessary spacing?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

[The application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YHBU.png)

As you can see it doesn't make the pushButtons equally big. Even though I created them with these properties

```
butt->setMaximumHeight(50);
butt->setMaximumWidth(50);
butt->setMinimumHeight(50);
butt->setMinimumWidth(50);
```

to make sure they have the exact size I want.

This is the part of my code where I create my buttons:

```
for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++){
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
        {
            QPushButton *butt = new QPushButton();
            butt->setMaximumHeight(50);
            butt->setMaximumWidth(50);
            butt->setMinimumHeight(50);
            butt->setMinimumWidth(50);
            ui->gridLayout->addWidget(butt, r, c);
            gameTable[r][c] = butt;
        }
    }
```

Here, gameTable is defined as following:

```
QPushButton *gameTable[10][10];
```

Also, as you can see, there are spaces between the columns. How do I get rid off them?

Comment: Can we see more of the code? Especially the part where you fiddle with the buttons and put them in the layout.

Comment: Added, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: The code you posted looks fine. I even tested it and it shows a perfect grid. Could the problem be somewhere else?

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem was in the size constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make gridLayout behave as intended, it is necessary to set size constraint to fixed:

```
ui->gridLayout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
```